# The library 'package:flutter/material.dart' is legacy, and should not be imported into a null safe library

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I have a null-safe library and in the example folder I'm using the following import:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

However, the linter is giving me the following warning:

> The library 'package:flutter/material.dart' is legacy, and should not be imported into a null safe library. Try migrating the imported library. import_of_legacy_library_into_null_safe

The example project's pubspec.yaml file specifies the beta version of the Dart SDK:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0-29.10.beta <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  my_library:
    path: ../
```

Hasn't material.dart already been converted by now? Do I need to add something else to pubspec.yaml or just wait for the stable release to come out?

Comment: Which flutter channel are you using? stable, beta, dev or master?

Comment: @rickimaru, I'm on the beta channel

Answer (score 40):

Use `dart pub outdated --mode=null-safety` and then `dart pub upgrade --null-safety` to upgrade all your dependencies to null-safety.

For more details go to https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide.

Comment: Why has this not been marked as the correct answer, literally a tool offered by Dart to resolve one of the most commonly faced Dart issues

Comment: omgg u r the king

Answer (score 21):

The fix for this is relatively simple.
Just go to your pubspec.yaml file and make sure the lottie dependancy that you have there, is the latest version as on the pub.dev site.

Comment: Just upgraded the faulty packages and it resolved the issue. Thanks bud upvoting your answer. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Currently, on 8/29/2021, a*uto_size_text package also keeps giving this alert*, because I was using the Null Safety versions of Dart - 2.12.0, and to solve this, I looked in the package documentation and saw that I had a **Prerelease version to Null Safety** - launch, so I used it.

```
dependencies:
  auto_size_text: ^3.0.0-nullsafety.0
```

Answer (score 2):

In case someone comes here looking for this error because of the flutter realm package.
Please change your realm version in your `pubspec.yaml` file  to a version with null safety. Check out the latest realm versions from https://pub.dev/packages/realm/versions.

Change From

```
dependencies
  realm: ^0.0.1
```

To

```
dependencies
   realm: ^0.8.0+rc  //check for latest version
```

Answer (score 2):

in my case my firebase_core package was not of the latest version. do check yours or any other firebase related dependencies. some packages maybe old version.

Answer (score 1):

[![The library 'package:flutter_*/*.dart' is legacy, and should not be imported into a null safe library. Try migrating the imported library.

Open run/debug option -> select edit configuration as shown in image one.][1](https://i.stack)][1](https://i.stack)

[image: And then add in --no-sound-null-safety in Additional run args section ->Apply->ok->run appllication it works for me].imgur.com/A9aEb.png

Comment: Add        --no-sound-null-safety  this in editconfigaration it works

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem with the *Adhan Dart* package, when i read the documentation on the package site , i had the Prereleased version so i made changes to the dependences as `adhan: ^2.0.0-nullsafety.2` and it worked.

For more details:https://pub.dev/packages/adhan/versions/2.0.0-nullsafety.1

Answer (score 0):

go to https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter,

copy the latest release version of font i.e in my case (font_awesome_flutter: ^9.1.0),

then add it to your pubspec.yaml file i.e (font_awesome_flutter: ^9.1.0),

click pub get dependencies

go to your input_page file

click get dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Copy the latest version of the package which is giving the error from http://pub.dev/ and paste it in the pubspec.yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got this error because I defined 'firebase_core' dependency in the pubspec.yaml file under the 'dev_dependencies' but it was wrong.

I've done 3 easy steps to solve the issue as following:

1- I've got the latest version from https://pub.dev/packages website.

2- I've defined the packages under 'dependencies' in the pubspec.yaml file as following:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^2.3.0
```

3- I've imported the package in the main.dart file as following:

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```