# The library 'package:vin_decoder/vin_decoder.dart' is legacy, and should not be imported into a null safe library

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to use a vin decoder package in my app. When I import the package:

```
import 'package:vin_decoder/vin_decoder.dart';
```

but I am getting this warning:

> The library 'package:vin_decoder/vin_decoder.dart' is legacy, and should not be imported into a null safe library.
> Try migrating the imported library.

My pubspec.yaml has this under dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  vin_decoder: ^0.1.4
```

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong? I checked out [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65949032/the-library-packageflutter-material-dart-is-legacy-and-should-not-be-importe) but nothing worked.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing nothing wrong. Currently this package has not released a null safety version yet, and you project is null safe. Check [package](https://pub.dev/packages/vin_decoder), there is a prerelease version `0.2.1-nullsafety`. Either wait for it to be released, or use this prerelease version, but of course it can contain bugs.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I need to do some research on null safety as well.