# 'package:splashscreen/splashscreen.dart' is legacy, and should not be imported into a null safe library

Tags: flutter, dart, pubspec

how to resolve this error of null safe library in splash screen even though I have added dependency most recent one i.e "splashscreen: ^1.3.5"
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hope this will help https://stackoverflow.com/q/65949032/2804581

Comment: no, I already seen that and that is for material package

Comment: can you add your flutter version and the target platform you are trying to run.

Comment: Flutter 2.2.3 • channel stable and android emulator - android 11.0

Comment: Can you share the version specified In your project pubspec.yaml

Comment: please check the image i added just now

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To import a package without null safety support reduce your flutter version in `pubspec.yaml`

Replace `environment` with bellow version

```
  environment:
    sdk: ">=2.06.0 <3.0.0"
```

**Note:** This is one way to use an external package without null safety support. If it's an existing project check your dependencies for null safety support before migrating.

Comment: how will it affect my project without null safety support

Comment: It's just a process of upgrading to the latest version. If you want the project to be up to date choose packages that provide regular updates or else start creating your own solution for the package or find an updated package. It's completely the developer's choice. Only staying up to date with the version and coding standard is the impact for the developer.